# Adding buttons to a XML file containing a ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview, button

I've been trying to implement three buttons in an XML file that contains a ListView. However, these buttons are being added to the individual views as they are added to the collection. Does anyone know how to separate these so that the buttons are separate from the ListView?

Thanks in advance!

Code for button XML

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ClearAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:onClick="onClickClearAll"
            android:text="Clear All Checks"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checkAll"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/checkAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:onClick="onClickCheckAll"
            android:text="Check All Devices"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ClearAll"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

ListView Code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
    </ListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Combined XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ClearAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/checkAll"
        android:onClick="onClickClearAll"
        android:text="Uncheck All" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:onClick="onClickCheckAll"
        android:text="Check All"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/passCredentials"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:onClick="onClickPassCredentials"
        android:text="Enter Credentials" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/device_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/ClearAll"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:cacheColorHint="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
    </ListView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is the `ListView` and `Buttons` in the same layout/xml?

Comment: As of right now, I have them separated into two separate xml but I am trying to combine them into the one. I'll update my code with my attempt.

Comment: @LostandConfused now whats the issue you are facing? you have already put in linear layout with vertical orientation. what you want to achieve

Comment: @WaqarUlHaq For each view within the ListView, all of the buttons are being displayed. I ideal would like to have one set of buttons and have the ListView be underneath as a separate entity. If that isn't clear I can always post a picture.

Comment: "...I am trying to combine them into the one." – Why? You need to have separate layouts for those; one for the `Activity`/`Fragment`/whatever that contains the `ListView`, and a separate one for the individual rows in the `ListView`. If I'm following you correctly, you want to move the `<ListView>` from the second layout above into the first. Then, the first layout is for your `Activity`/`Fragment`/whatever, and the second one is what you use for the `ListView`'s `Adapter`.

Comment: @MikeM. "I am trying to combine them into the one" I was talking about combining the separate xml files into one file with multiple layouts. Sorry for the confusion, when I posted the third block of code it was more so to see the general picture rather than show my attempts at using multiple layouts to achieve my goal. However, when I have tried what you suggested I am still getting the same result as each of the views in the ListView still contain the buttons. I will update my code to reflect my attempt. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each layout needs to be in its own separate file. You can't put the `ListView` row layout in the same layout file that the `ListView` itself is in. Anyhoo, if you moved the `<ListView>` as I suggested, and you're getting `Button`s in the individual `ListView` items, then you're using the wrong layout for the `Adapter`. After the move, the first layout above will be for the `Activity`/`Fragment`/whatever. The second layout – which should now have only two `<TextView>`s and a `<CheckBox>` – is what you use in the `Adapter`.